# impl Trait for primitives and references of

Tags: rust, reference, traits

Perhaps it is a simple question, but I can't understand why just impl'ing Trait for the primitive, owned type, I got for free the same impl for reference types...

```rust
trait Cool: Sized + std::fmt::Debug {
    fn cool(self) {
        println!("cool -> {:?}", self);
    }
}

impl Cool for i32 {}

// it still works if this line is uncommented...
// impl Cool for &i32 {}

fn main(){
    let val = 123;
    val.cool();
    (&val).cool();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=84ee60c955b4eb8dfad01ea9843e64ee)

Comment: Essentially method lookup for `&&&i32` will look for implementations for `&&&i32`, `&&i32`, `&i32`, and `i32` (which the last only works because `i32` is `Copy`).

Comment: Note that `&i32` **does not** implement `Cool` unless you explicitly do so; you can call it _as if it would_ because of autoref, but you can't pass it for example to a function that expects `impl Cool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not just because of primitives, **it will work for all types that implement [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#)**. Will not work otherwise:

```rust
trait Cool: Sized + std::fmt::Debug {
    fn cool(self) {
        println!("cool -> {:?}", self);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct NonCopy;

impl Cool for i32 {}
impl Cool for NonCopy {}

fn main(){
    let val = 123;
    val.cool();
    (&val).cool();
    
    let nc = NonCopy{};
    nc.cool();
    (&nc).cool();
}
```

Fails with a clear error code:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:20:5
   |
20 |     (&nc).cool();
   |     ^^^^^^------
   |     |     |
   |     |     value moved due to this method call
   |     move occurs because value has type `NonCopy`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7295bcac787f2a978dd8d37fabb02a3c)

What it's happening is that with the Copy types rust creates a copy transparently for you when needed.

Note that it fails even if we comment out the previous line `// nc.cool();`, which obviously moves the value...

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Netwave! It is cool that, if we "impl Cool for &NonCopy {}", then both method calls work!

Comment: @rsalmei, yes, because in that case you will be moving the reference.

Answer (score 1):

That's auto-dereferencing; it applies whenever you use the `.` operator. It's meant to erase the distinction between `.` and `->` which exists in C and related languages.

It was introduced in [RFC 241](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0241-deref-conversions.md).

Comment: Thanks @coriolinus, I've read more about the dot operator on the nomicon... wow!